# Php if statements/contact form anti spam integration

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am trying to integrate [this tutorial](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/11/how-to-build-a-spam-free-contact-forms-without-captchas/) into my existing contact form. However if it not working. Basically I want to have a blank url input field that I hide with CSS. If that field is filled in the form will not send. Here is my original mailer script:

```
<?php
// My modifications to mailer script from:
// http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
// Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "rrswans@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        //http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Message Received! Click to close. ";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        //http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
   // http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

?>

This is the code that I need to integrate in...

```
<?php 
// if the url field is empty 
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){
     // then send the form to your email
      mail( 'you@yoursite.com', 'Contact Form', print_r($_POST,true) ); 
} 
// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
?>
```

I'm sure this is easy enough, I just don't know PHP very well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing :

```
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {...
```

To:

```
    if (isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '' &&
       mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {...
```

Also, your hidden input is known as a 'honey pot' and it is known to be more effective if set to :

```
position:absolute;
top: -100;
```

rather than

```
display:none
```

**EDIT**

I forgot that the if statement validates from left to right, please see revision above.
also make sure your input is named 'url'

```
<input name="url" />
```

Comment: Well that gets the form to send, but does not prevent it from not sending when there is text in the 'honey pot'